# Solving $ A \sin^2(\theta - \delta) = B - C \sin(\delta) $ for $\delta$

Tags: trigonometry

I have been trying a certain trigonometric equation but I am struggling to solve it by hand. I am not supposed to use a calculator or an online tool for solving this.

The equation is as follows:
$$ A \sin^2(\theta - \delta) = B - C \sin(\delta) $$

In this equation, $A$, $B$, $C$ and $\theta$ are known to me. However I am unable to solve this for the value of $\delta$ as I have tried expanding $\sin^2(\theta - \delta)$  in $\sin(A-B)$ form but it gives a fourth order equation that is non trivial to solve.

The value of $\theta$ is close to $\pi/2$. So it's a fair assumption to transform $\sin^2(\theta - \delta)$ to $(1-\sin^2(\delta))$ form and then solve the resulting quadratic equation. However I have been asked to solve it to the accurate value of $\theta$.

**How do I proceed to solve this equation?**

Comment: Not clear to me if it's a numerical problem or a problem of exact factorisation?

Comment: @GabrielSoranzo I was thinking of factorization in terms of the parameters. We can always plug in values if the factors are correct.

Comment: Can you share the values of all constants? They can induce specific approximations.

Comment: From what I can tell, the problem ultimately turns into an unattractive quartic. While there is [a formula for the roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) of such things, it's not fun to implement. (*Mathematica* isn't giving me a nice result, either.) Do you (or the person who tasked you with this) have reason to believe there's a reasonable symbolic answer?

Comment: @Blue no, I don't think so. The values of A, B, C, etc are based on real-world numbers. So, it's unlikely they produce anything clever. I was just interested to know if there is a way to solve this without resorting to fourth order equations.

Comment: @Sid: I think an irreducible quartic is unavoidable. However, it need not be as unattractive as I suggested. Using complex exponentials and defining $p:=\exp(i\delta)$ and $q:=\exp(i\theta)$, you can write 
$$Ap^4 + 2 i C p^3 q^2 -2 (A - 2 B) p^2q^2 -2 iC p q^2 + q^4  = 0$$ Still not fun, though.

Comment: With $X=\cos\delta$, $Y=\sin\delta$, $\sigma=\sin\theta$ and $\gamma=\cos\theta$ I find $$A\sigma^2X^2-2\sigma\gamma XY+\gamma^2 Y^2+CY-B=0$$ whose (as a conic) discriminant is something like $\frac{\sigma^2}{4}(-C^2A+4B\gamma^2(1-A))$. So if you want to factorise ($\Delta=0\iff$ union of two lines) this discriminant should be 0...